# How to calculate the average point of each student on each course by mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I will use the above example to make you clear.

```
student_id | c1 | c2 | c3 | c4
         1 | 85 | 90 | 73 | 99
         2 | 56 | 85 | 86 | 96
         3 | 23 | 74 | 54 | 88
```

My Question is how to calculate the average score of all the students at the same time. The result would show the average score of each of them . I hope you know what I mean

Comment: Normalise your schema

Comment: Can you describe what the fields of your table mean?

Answer (score 1):

A normalised design might look like this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE student_scores
(student_id INT NOT NULL
,course_id INT NOT NULL
,score INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO student_scores VALUES
(1,1,85),
(2,1,56),
(3,1,23),
(1,2,90),
(2,2,85),
(3,2,74),
(1,3,73),
(2,3,86),
(3,3,54),
(1,4,99),
(2,4,96),
(3,4,88);
```

From here, calculating the average score for each student should be obvious.

Comment: I think OP is new and probably doesn't know how to do the average for each.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a query for that this way

```
select  student_id,
        (c1 + c2 + c3 + c4) / 4 as averageScore
from    yourTable
```

If you want the overall average instead, you can do that like this

```
select  sum(c1) + sum(c2) + sum(c3) + sum(c4) / (count(distinct student_id) * 4)
from    yourTable
```

**Edit**

To get the average of each column among all students you can use the `avg` aggregation function

```
select  avg(c1) as avg_c1,
        avg(c2) as avg_c2,
        avg(c3) as avg_c3, 
        avg(c4) as avg_c4
from    yourTable
```

Comment: Hi, I think the first statement only focuses on a specific student. In the case, I have 4 students and want to calculate the average point of the 4 students in a statement.  Do you have another idea ?

Comment: Do you want the average score across all the students for each column separately?

Comment: Yes I do . Please help

Comment: Glad it helped! If this **or any other** answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.